# find median for $0<x<1$ $f(x)=2x$ where $0<x<1$

Tags: statistics

find median for $0<x<1$ $f(x)=2x$  where $0<x<1$

---

**Attempt**

$ \int^1_0 2x^2 dx = 2 [\frac{x^3}{3}]^1_0=\frac{2}{3}[x^3]^1_0=2/3$

but I am told that the answer is $3/4$. Why am I wrong?? to get the median one just multiplies it by x and then integrates???

Comment: You calculated mean. $m$ is [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions) iff $P(X\geq m)\geq\frac12$ and $P(X\leq m)\geq\frac12$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong because you are mixing the definition of mean and median. To get the mean you multiply by $x$ and integrate. To get the median you are looking for a number $M$ such that
$$\int_0^M f(x)\,dx=\int_M^1f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

The answer is not $\frac{3}{4}$.